# React Invalid Token getting unauthorized, using axios , also unable to logout

Tags: reactjs, django, authentication, axios, token

React Invalid Token getting unauthorized, using Axios, also unable to logout from user account

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
The token does not exist in the backend but is there in frontend local storage, steps for removing from frontend 
    1. Go inside dev tools (ctrl +shift + i) then 
    2. Select Application 
    3.Inside the Application go to Storage then 
    4. Open Local Storage (double click on local storage) then
    5. Clear local storage
```